# expectation over a minimum continuous variable $t$

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value

Let $X \geq 0$ a random variable.Using only the definition of the expectation (without using Fatou Lemma, BCT,MCT) how can I show that : $$\lim_{t \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[X \wedge t] = \mathbb{E}[X],$$ where $t$ is a continous variable , i.e $t \in \mathbb{R}.$
my effort is that
assuming that $t > 0$ otherwise $X \wedge t = t$ which is trivial. Then $Y := X \wedge t$ is a nonnegative variable and we have

\begin{align*}
E[Y] &= \int_0^\infty P( Y > k) dt \\
       &= \int_0^\infty P( X > k, t > k) dt \\
       &= \int_0^\infty P( X > t)\mathbf{1}\{ t > k\} dt \\
       &= \int_0^t P(X > k)dt
\end{align*}

Comment: What does "$k$" represent in your calculations??

Comment: Jumping on what @whuber said, you should not use t as your variable of integration in the first step. Use dk instead of dt and your calculations will be correct. Then take the limit as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the survival function of $X,$

$$S(x) = \Pr(X\gt x),$$

and for $t\ge 0$ let $S_t$ be the survival function of $X\wedge t.$  For $x\ge t,$

$$S_t(x) = \Pr(X\wedge t\gt x) = 0$$

and otherwise for $x\lt t,$

$$S_t(x) = \Pr(X\wedge t \gt x) = \Pr(X \gt x) = S(x).$$

Thus

$$E[X\wedge t] = \int_0^\infty S_t(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^t S(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

You can carry out the rest of the demonstration from here.

Comment: How ? by integrating $\int_{0}^{t}P(X>x)dt$?

Comment: $\begin{align*}
E[Y] &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}( Y > k) dk \\
       &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}( X > k, t > k) dk \\
       &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}( X > t)\mathbf{1}\{ t > k\} dk \\
       &= \int_0^t \mathbb{P}(X > k)dk
\end{align*}$

Comment: Take the limit as $t\to\infty.$

Comment: as this one that you said yesterday $$\mathbb E[X\wedge t] = \int_0^\infty\mathbb P(X\wedge t>k) d k =\int_0^t\mathbb P(X>k) d k.$$
Now 
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbb E[X\wedge t]=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t\mathbb P(X>k) d k=\int_0^\infty\mathbb P(X>k) dk=\mathbb E[X].$$